# Поиск по многомерному массиву с array_search();

Tags: массивы, php

Привет профессионалы, немного застопорился на поиске по "одному значению". Есть код:

```
<?php

$out_data = array (
    array("01_composita","Composita"),
    array("02_composita_p","Composita Plus"),
    array("03_contemporanea","Contemporanea"),
    array("04_epc","Epc"),
    array("05_hotel","Hotel"),
    array("06_plain_filomuro","Plait Filomuro"),
    array("07_pds","Pds"),
    array("08_soluzione","Soluzione"),
    array("09_teknoeuropa","Teknoeuropa"),
    array("10_telemako","Telemako")
);

$tmp = array_search(array("05_hotel","Hotel"), $out_data);

var_dump ($tmp); // выдает 4

?>
```

Тут иголка ('needle') у меня: array("05_hotel","Hotel"), но я знаю только первое значение: '05_hotel'. Возможно ли найти ключ 'parent' массива, где в 'child' массиве первое значение известно, а второе - любое? (без for, foreach). Спасибо за внимание.

P.S> Я как бы написал такое чудо:

```
$needle = '05_hotel';

$result = false;
foreach ($out_data as $key => $val) {
    if ($val[0] == $needle) { $result = $key; break; }
}

var_dump($result);
```

Но мне кажется есть что то проще, и с array_seacrh();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не претендую на самое елегентное решение, но работать точно будет

```
<?php
$out_data = array (
    array("01_composita","Composita"),
    array("02_composita_p","Composita Plus"),
    array("03_contemporanea","Contemporanea"),
    array("04_epc","Epc"),
    array("05_hotel","Hotel"),
    array("06_plain_filomuro","Plait Filomuro"),
    array("07_pds","Pds"),
    array("08_soluzione","Soluzione"),
    array("09_teknoeuropa","Teknoeuropa"),
    array("10_telemako","Telemako"),
    array("08_soluzione","Telemako")
);

//Ищем
$needle = "08_soluzione";

//Собственно поиск
$result = array_filter($out_data, function($innerArray){
    global $needle;
    //return in_array($needle, $innerArray);    //Поиск по всему массиву
    return ($innerArray[0] == $needle); //Поиск по первому значению
});

//Результат
echo '<pre>'.print_r($result, true).'</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: Ага! Очень даже -- спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста :)
Полагаю, об array_keys() не надо уже писать, сами сделаете для получения именно индексов

Comment: Да, интересно что быстрее работает ваш пример или с foreach)

Comment: Полагаю, итерации array_filter() на уровне интерпретатора должны работать быстрее, но 100% гарантий дать не могу.

UPD. Проверил, ваш работает в 2 раза быстрее :) если сохранить результат в том виде, в котором его возвращает array_filter(), если урезать до выбора только ключа + break, то в 3-3.5 раза :)

Comment: Ого спасибо! Я почему то так и думал что array_filter() переберёт в конечном итоге весь массив, а для моей задачи достаточно только первого результата

Comment: Я убирал break, все-равно быстрее работает. Наверное array_filter как-то "непонятно" реализирован, или же такое "торможение" вызвано передачей callbacka в каждой итерации (имеются ввиду итерации при тестировании)

Answer (score 0):

Вариант в копилку c [array_column](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-column.php) (PHP 5 >= 5.5.0). Возвращает ключи массива.

```
$result = array_keys(array_column($out_data, 0), $needle);

Array
(
    [0] => 7
    [1] => 10
)
```