# Функция для работы с массивами PHP

Tags: php

какой функцией для работы с массивами можно заменить foreach в таком коде

```
$users = array(
        array(
            'login' => 'test',
            'pass' => 'aaa',
            'email' => 'test@aaa'
        ),
        array(
            'login' => 'admin',
            'pass' => 'aaa',
            'email' => 'admin@aaa'
        ),
    );
$login_exist = false;
 foreach ($users as $val) {
        if ($val['login'] === $login) {
            $login_exist = true;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```
$login = 'test';
print_r(in_array($login, array_column($users, 'login')));
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ab8dfbba5d6af384347b145e19aa8e25fd01e88c

Но я считаю, что проще одним циклом. Потому что в схеме выше будет аж два цикла. Но зато кода меньше

Comment: пробовал так выдавало ошибку, сейчас пробую все работает. Спасибо!!!

Comment: @vasyajidko не могу представить ошибку. разве что из-за старой версии php. Но в целом должно работать. Вынесли бы вы свой код в функцию и пользовались бы ею. Эффективнее было бы

Comment: ага так и сделаю, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Можно вот так:

```
$needle = 'qwe';
$result = !empty(array_filter($users,
function ($innerArray) use ($needle)
    {
    return ($innerArray['login'] == $needle);
    }));

var_dump((bool)$result);
```

[Пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/15c3412dc2219230d20cb003b212061e35fd9ec7).

Взято [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/255834/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%83-%D1%81-array-search).

Comment: зачем `global`? надо function ($innerArray) use ($needle)

Comment: @МишаХромов, спасибо, поправил